# MySQL STR_TO_DATE seems to fail when day has a "0"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, date

I have a series of dates in my database that are in String format.

I am trying to convert these to date using the following command:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y')FROM urls WHERE Date_Scanned 
BETWEEN "01/02/2018" AND "05/04/2018"
```

My problem seems to occur when the day contains a 0, for example the below command returns all desired dates:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y')FROM urls WHERE Date_Scanned 
BETWEEN "01/02/2018" AND "15/04/2018"
```

However, this command returns zero results:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y')FROM urls WHERE Date_Scanned 
BETWEEN "01/02/2018" AND "05/04/2018"
```

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE("05/04/2018", '%d/%m/%Y') works fine so what does date_scanned look like. did you mean you have dates like '00/02/2018'?

Comment: Date_Scanned also has time attached to the string, e.g:

19/02/2018 11:38:32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no error in your code but instead it is returning empty row. The reason is because the parameter you are passing is evaluated as a string and not as a date. Your `WHERE` clause filters the column `Date_Scanned` in string.

If you wanted to filter the column based on *real* date datatype, you should be using the `STR_TO_DATE()` in the `WHERE` clause and not in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM urls 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-04-05'
```

However, based on your comment, you wanted to stick the format you want so you have to cast the column as well as the value. *But why make it more complicated?*

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Date_Scanned, '%d/%m/%Y') 
      BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2018', '%d/%m/%Y') 
              AND STR_TO_DATE('05/04/2018', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: This does work if I use the date format you provided in the between ('2018-02-01').

However, it doesn't work with my desired date format ('02/03/2018')

Comment: then cast both column and value to date.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by just changing a split function I had somewhere else in my code!

Thanks so much for the help!